# Show header for all pages except home page in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to ReactJS and I want the header to be shown for all pages except the Home page <Route path='/' element={ }/>.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Header/>
          <Routes>
              <Route path='/' element={ <Home/>}/>
              <Route path='/Breakfast' element={<Breakfast/>}/>
              <Route path='/Lunch' element={<Lunch/>}/>
              <Route path='/Snacks' element={<Snacks/>}/>
              <Route path='/Dinner' element={<Dinner/>}/>
              <Route path='/Drinks' element={<Drinks/>}/>
              <Route path='/NightLife' element={<NightLife/>}/>
          </Routes>
          <Footer/>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: where is the header component ?

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to move your `<Header />` component into a `<Layout />` component (which is something I usually do). Reason why is that you can't conditionally check a route outside of a `<Router />` context, meaning you can't do it in your `<App />` component.

The layout would take a `children` prop and check if the current route is the homepage:

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  return (
    <div>
      {pathname !== "/" ? <Header /> : null}
      <div>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Check out an example here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-christian-ujpqz?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the whole page in a Layout and only render the Header if the current page is not the homepage.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/blogs" element={<Blogs />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And providing the Layout like this:

```
const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {!(path="/") && <Header />}
      <Outlet />
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
};
```

W3Schools has a pretty good documentation for this!